# Amazon S3 Images not showing up in Assets

Tags: assets, s3, amazon

I'm developing locally and adding images to my Amazon S3 bucket. I have the same connection to the bucket on my remote environment. On my local environment, I can see the images I've uploaded, but on my remote environment none of the images that I uploaded locally are showing when I browse assets.

On my remote environment, if I attempt to re-upload the image, I get a message: A file with the name “mylogo.svg” already exists. So I know that the assets field is correctly connected to the bucket in the remote environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend updating the asset indexes via *Utilities → Asset Indexes* (or *Settings → Update Asset Indexes* if you're on Craft 2) in your Control Panel.